# Why doesn't my template get rendered in the browser?

Tags: html, go

I want to render a template to the browser. However, nothing shows up. 
Here's the code I'm running, **main.go**:

```
    package main

    import (
        "html/template"
        "net/http"
        "log"
    )


    func main() {
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        mux.HandleFunc("/", home)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8000", mux))
    }


    func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := pageData{"MyTabTitle", "MyPageName"}

        tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("base.html"))
        tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    }


    type pageData struct {
        tabTitle, pageName string
    }
```

In the same directory I also have the **base.html**-file

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> {{ .tabTitle }}
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1> {{ .pageName }} </h1>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're ignoring errors. Don't do that. The error will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Also a note on terminology: The template doesn't render in the browser at all. It renders on the server, then is sent to the browser. If you want rendering in the browser, you must use client-side code, probably written in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say I ignore errors, are you referring to **html/template.Template.Must**?

Comment: @KentMartin The error returned from `tmpl.Execute(w, data)` is ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields of pageData are not exported, so the template engine cannot access them. Capitalize the field names and the references to those in the template. Also, do not ignore the template execution errors.

Comment: There's also a good chance it cannot find the template--the local directory during compilation has nothing to do with the local directory during execution.

Comment: Good catch, @Flimzy. The way `net/http` is written, makes all panics in HTTP handlers be caught and logged; so they should appear on the program's standard error stream. Since the panics are caught and logged, the program does not blow up even if `template.Must` supposedly does.

Comment: Thank you both for the input. I have capitalized the fields in _pageData_ but I still can't see anything in the browser. I'm new to **Go** and don't really know what I'm doing, but I get that I should look into error-handling next.

Comment: After inspecting the error returned by **tmpl.Execute()** I found that I had forgotten to close the `<title>`-tag in _base.html_. Now everything works as expected. Again, thanks for the help.